# Prove sensitivity to initial conditions numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

How can I prove sensitivity to initial conditions numerically? 
I mean directly from the computed data and neglecting the dynamical system that originated the data.

The data comes from hybrid dynamical system (ode + resets when a value is reached) that can be considered as a discrete dynamical system.

Thanks.

Comment: A simple thing to try would be to tweak the initial conditions.

Comment: Yes. But how do I measure in some significant way that the differences while changing the i.c. mean sensitivity?

Comment: For discrete dynamical systems, one can compute an estimate of the Liapunov exponent from the data, and if that estimate is positive then one can take it as evidence of sensitive dependence on initial conditions. But by the differential-equations tag, I take it you are interested in continuous dynamical systems. Maybe there is an analogous computation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My case is a continous system with discrete resets when a value is reached. Therefore it can be considered as discrete. It would be of enormous help to get a reference on how to perform that estimate of Liapunov!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an whole field of study related with the extraction of Lyapunov exponents from time-series, for instance to distinguish noise from chaotic behavior.

A definite starting point is [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960194909911) from H. Kantz.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise *sensitivity to initial conditions* is physicists language for the fact that a small change in the initial conditions grows exponentially in time.

**Numerically**, just check if for two solutions the distance $|x(t)-y(t)|$ grows exponentially in time $t$ for slightly different initial conditions $y_0=x_0+\epsilon$.

**Formally**, for $|\epsilon|\to 0$ and $t\to\infty$ the exponent of this dependence, if it exists, is the Lyapunov exponent mentioned in the comments.

Comment: If the data is bounded and oscillating, I don't see how to implement this.

Comment: Chaotic motion is also possible in a bounded space. The exponential depence (if existing) can only be observed for a finite time, say $T$, then it saturates. For smaller $\epsilon$ this duration $T$ grows. Only for an infinitesimal displacement $\epsilon$ the exponential growth would last forever, $T\to\infty$. This follows from the two limits competing against each other as mentioned in the answer. In more illustrative words: in a finite interval, there is room for exponential growth, as long as you choose the thing you want to grow to be small enough.

Comment: You can normalize the distances after a few steps (say, anytime it becomes bigger than 1/100 of the domain size). And keep repeating your numerical experiment.

Answer (score 0):

In view of the discussion in the comments, I'll post an answer concerning the Liapunov exponent, even though I'm not sure it will be helpful here.

Given a discrete dynamical system, which for my purposes here is a differentiable function $f$, a starting point $x_0$, and a sequence of iterates $x_1,x_2,\dots$ given by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, the Lyapunov exponent of $f$ at $x_0$ is given by $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^n\log|f'(x_k)|$$ provided the limit exists. It is common in applications for the limit to exist and to be independent of the initial value $x_0$. A limit exceeding zero is indicative of sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

In practice, one generally cannot compute this quantity exactly, so one approximates it by $${1\over n}\sum_{k=m+1}^{m+n}\log|f'(x_k)|$$ for some appropriate $m$ and $n$, say, $m=n=500$.

Comment: Well true. The problem is when we don't know $f$. My question is if there is anyways to approximate this without knowing $f$. Just with the values $x_1,x_2\dots$.

Comment: Sorry, then, I'm out of ideas.